# React setState rendering behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a question concerning the rendering behavior of those two options:

```
export function saveOrCancelStepContentComponents(stepIndex, targetArray, newArray) {
    // Option 1
    let stepsData = this.state.stepsData.slice();
    stepsData[stepIndex][targetArray] = newArray;

    this.setState({stepsData: stepsData}, () => {
        console.log("saveStepConditions[]:", this.state.stepsData[stepIndex][targetArray]);
    });

    // Option 2
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        stepsData: prevState.stepsData.map((currentStep, i) => {
            if (i === stepIndex) {
                return {
                    ...currentStep,
                    [targetArray]: newArray,
                }
            }
            return currentStep
        })
    }), () => {
        console.log("saveStepConditions[]:", this.state.stepsData[stepIndex][targetArray]);
    });
}
```

Canceling and saving works with both options, which is to say that the console.logs are fine. However, only option 2 re-renders the page. Going with option 1 won't result in any phenotype changes.
Any ideas why that is? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `stepsData[stepIndex][targetArray] = newArray;` mutates `stepsData[stepIndex]` object instead of creating a new one.

It should be like

```
stepsData[stepIndex] = {
   ...stepsData[stepIndex],
   [targetArray]: newArray
}
```

The same way you did inside map function.

Comment: So if I want to splice an element I would do the same?

`stepsData[stepIndex].contentComponents = {
                ...stepsData[stepIndex],
                contentComponents: stepsData[stepIndex].contentComponents.splice(i, 1)
            };`

Comment: @Nocebo Forget about `splice`. It mutates original array and returns spliced elements. Use `filter` instead.

Comment: So filter doesn't mutate the object?
Should it be smth like this: 
`stepsData[stepIndex].contentComponents = {
                    ...stepsData[stepIndex].contentComponents,
                    contentComponents:  stepsData[stepIndex].contentComponents.filter((component) => {
                        return component.deleteId === deleteId
                    })
                };`
or this:

`stepsData[stepIndex].contentComponents.filter((component) => {
                        return component.deleteId === deleteId
                    })`

Comment: @Nocebo It returns new array. So the first option: you need to save the result back to a property of newly created object. BTW you need `component.deleteId !== deleteId` because `filter` keeps elements matching the predicate.